# Sort nested serializer objects in Django

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have 2 serializers, one of them includes nested Serializer with `many=True`. I want to sort `steps` field by `service_id`. Including `ordering=("service_id")` into StepSerializer didn't help. How can I perform `steps` sort in nested Serializer?

```
class StepSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 class Meta:
    model = Step
    fields = ("pk", "service_id", "create_date", "update_date",)


class LessonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 steps = StepSerializer(many=True)

 class Meta:
    model = Lesson
    fields = ("pk", "service_id", "create_date","steps_count", "steps")
```

Models:

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
 service_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
 create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
 update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
 steps_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Step(models.Model):
 service_id = models.IntegerField()
 create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
 update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
 lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lesson, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="steps")
```

Comment: Try `ordering = ("service_id", )` and migrate... `ordering` needs to be a tuple so don't forget the comma.

Comment: @zaidfazil django can't detect this and says "no changes detected"

Comment: Have you ran `python manage.py makemigrations <your_app_name>`?

Comment: @zaidfazil yes, unfortunately

Comment: Could you post your models for that, please..?

Comment: @zaidfazil done

Comment: Do you want to change your default ordering of `Step` model according to the `service_id`, or do you need it for just this case only?

Comment: @zaidfazil in this case